# Can't delete duplicate strings with shell commands

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file called "*1.txt*" which contains the following:

```
111
111
222
777
1111
777
```

I'm trying to delete duplicate strings from it. Both `sort -u 1.txt` and `sort 1.txt | uniq` return this:

```
111
1111
222
777
777
```

**Question:**

Why is the string "777" still contained *twice*? How to remove the duplicate?

Comment: Check 1.txt for trailing spaces/tabs.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this issue. I copied and pasted your above numbers and tried the same commands and got the desired output.

You might have some invisible characters in your file...

Comment: Try viewing the file with `LC_ALL=C cat -vet 1.txt` -- that will show normally-invisible  and non-ASCII characters in visible format, including showing newlines (line endings) as "$". I bet this will show a difference between the two "777" lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, one of the "777" has a hidden character at the end.
Try checking the length of each line of your file with:

```
$ awk '{ print length($0); }' 1.txt
```

Compare the length of both "777" lines, they should be different in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **sed** to delete non-digit char at the end of line, then use **sort** and **uniq** to delete duplicate string.

```
sed  's/[^0-9]\{0,\}$//' 1.txt | sort | uniq

where s : to replace matched string 
      [^0-9] : to match non-digit char
      \{0,\} : zero or more pattern match
      $ : matches the end of lines
```